# Microsoft Graph client error : Authentication challenge is required error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a Blazor server side .Net 5.0 application that allows a user to delete a user from Azure AD B2C after he has logged in. I am using the information contained in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp). I am getting a `Message: Authentication challenge is required.` error.

What could I be missing?

**Code to delete user using Azure AD B2C:**

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
public async Task DeleteUser(string id)

        {
            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(this.azureADB2C.ClientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(this.azureADB2C.RedirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(this.azureADB2C.ClientSecret)
                .Build();
            var authorizationCodeProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authorizationCodeProvider );
            await graphClient.Users[id].Request().DeleteAsync();
        }
```

**AppSettings.json:**

```
"AzureADB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://InstaTranscribe.b2clogin.com/",
    "Domain": "InstaTranscribe.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignInUserFlow",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordResetUserFlow",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEditingUserFlow",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:20000/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "<ClientSecret>"
  },
```

[image: Platform Configuration]

[image: API Permissions]

**Exception Stack:**

```
Status Code: 0
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.

 ---> Microsoft.Graph.Auth.AuthenticationException: Code: authenticationChallengeRequired
Message: Authentication challenge is required.

   at Microsoft.Graph.Auth.AuthorizationCodeProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
   at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.UserRequest.DeleteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Services.SecurityService.DeleteUser(String id) in C:\temp\InstaTranscribeServerSide\Services\SecurityService.cs:line 109
   at InstaTranscribeServerSide.Pages.DeleteAccountComponent.EditForm_OnValidSubmit() in C:\temp\InstaTranscribeServerSide\server\Pages\DeleteAccount.razor.designer.cs:line 62
```

**Update 1:**

**Stack Trace:**

```
Status Code: Unauthorized
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Authorization_IdentityNotFound
Message: The identity of the calling application could not be established.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-04-12T04:15:43
    request-id: 758804d0-075b-4946-94cb-af7241feedd1
    client-request-id: 758804d0-075b-4946-94cb-af7241feedd1
ClientRequestId: 758804d0-075b-4946-94cb-af7241feedd1

   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendRequestAsync(Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at Microsoft.Graph.UserRequest.DeleteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Services.SecurityService.DeleteUser(String id) in C:\temp\InstaTranscribeServerSide\Services\SecurityService.cs:line 109
   at InstaTranscribeServerSide.Pages.DeleteAccountComponent.EditForm_OnValidSubmit() in C:\temp\InstaTranscribeServerSide\server\Pages\DeleteAccount.razor.designer.cs:line 62
```

[image: API Permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to use Application token (you assign the **Application permission** in the app registration) to delete the user.

In this case you should use `ClientCredentialProvider` rather than `AuthorizationCodeProvider`.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
```

Don't forget to click on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}" on Azure Portal.

Comment: Thanks @AllenWu, I am now getting a "The identity of the calling application could not be established" error. Please see update 1 above.

Comment: @AjitGoel Sorry. I forget to update the code for `confidentialClientApplication`. Have updated the answer. Please check it.

Comment: @AjitGoel This error is caused by not specifying the tenant id.

Comment: Thanks @AllenWu, There is no way I could have fixed this issue without your help. Thanks once again.